# How to add an SPI to java sound in an eclipse project?

Tags: java, audio, mp3, javasound

I'm making a media player like java application and I'm using a bunch of different SPIs to provide support for various audio types. I was hoping that adding them would be just as easy as copying them into my project, then adding them to the build path, but I'm still getting an "javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException" when I try to make a call to AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file). I'm trying to play an MP3 file using the MP3SPI (http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html). I've also copied the jars into the java lib/ext directory, but I'm still not having any luck. Any idea what could be up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure which of your two posts to answer. Usually reposting is discouraged, I think.

I looked at i.imgur.com/0oeUi.jpg, and am wondering: where are the JLayer and Tritonius jars? The documentation for this spi states:

> Make sure that JLayer, Tritonus and MP3SPI librairies are available in your CLASSPATH. It means that you have jl1.0.1.jar, tritonus_share.jar, mp3spi1.9.5.jar in your CLASSPATH.

http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html

These jars are in the lib directory of the Javazoom download.

Comment: I'm sorry for the repost, I'm sure its discouraged but I was getting a bit frustrated. Thanks for the info though, that sounds like exactly what I was missing. Now I feel stupid :), but thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon, I added the Tritonius and JLayer libraries to the build path and to jre/lib/ext but I still am having trouble getting the audioInputStream. Here's how my classpath looks now: http://i.imgur.com/fjY9t.png

Comment: Glad I could help some. It looks like they provide a test or example program in the download. Does that run for you? Also, if you are still trying to establish that your program is finding these jars, as a test, you could look for public classes within them and try instantiating.

Comment: Sure thing! I took the test program they wrote and set up a project with it, but still no dice. Here's what my setup looks like: http://i.imgur.com/etXrK.jpg I was also able to instantiate public classes within each of the three libraries. Thanks for the help by the way, I'd really love to figure this one out

Comment: Sorry to bug, but you're the only person that i've been able to find that's given me any help.

Comment: Hi - if you can instantiate, that's great! Here is something to try: where you pass in the Filename string, instead of making a File, create a URL. Then, use your URL when you define "in". (I can't make out the code behind the config display.) Sometimes Java has trouble because the source for InputStreams has to be "Markable". If you use URL for getAudioInputStream(url), the intermediate InputStream is bypassed, and the "Markability" of your file is not an issue.

Comment: Concerning URL vs File, I don't have a clear enough grasp yet of how exceptions are handled. It seems to me if the issue was "Mark/reset error" when you make "in" then that's where the code should have triggered the exception. So that makes my above suggestion a bit of a long shot. Still, URL is better form I think and won't hurt.             I did have something else as a possibility, but I am kind of just guessing. Can you do this: 1) make and play a wav. 2) encode the wav as mp3. 3) THEN try your code. This would ensure that the underlying data in the encoded wav itself was the problem.

Comment: I love you. That worked. I actually just changed in to:  AudioInputStream in= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file.toURL()); You are my savior thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Add the SPI to the run-time class-path of the app.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0oeUi.jpg is this what you mean? I see the jars in here so apparently they're added...?

Comment: I don't provide support for Eclipse.

Comment: I switched over to netbeans. I'm having trouble getting any support for this issue. http://i.imgur.com/Z6SZ1.jpg Is this what it should look like?